# how to split the logs which only from aop after throwing advice...

Tags: spring-aop

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ThrowsLoggingAdvice.class);

public void afterThrowing(Method method, Object[] arguments, Object target, BatchException ex) throws Throwable {
    BatchException batchException=ex;
    Logger.getLogger(target.getClass()).debug("afterThrowing: BatchException");
    logger.error(ex.getMessage());
}
```